# How to pass directly a vector from Cuda to LibSVM struct?

Tags: pointers, cuda, libsvm

I'm using LibSVM in a project which I am trying to parallelize with CUDA.
The problem is that before train and prediction I store the useful data in a struct defined as

```
struct svm_node
{
    int index;
    double value;
};
```

and allocated, for example, in this way:

```
struct svm_node** testnode;

testnode = (struct svm_node**)malloc(sz[0] * sz[1] * sizeof(struct svm_node*));

for(i=0; i<sz[0] * sz[1]; i++){
    testnode[i] = (struct svm_node*)malloc((no_classes * tnum + 2) * sizeof(struct svm_node));
}
```

So, practically I have a matrix which I access, for instance, in this way

```
testnode[0][0].index;
testnode[0][0].value;
```

Now, *index* and *value* are obtained using CUDA and they are stored in two continuous vector (linearized matrices). Is there any way to directly bound the vector pointer of each to the testnode struct in order to "transfer" data without using any for loop ?

Comment: "So, practically I have a matrix" -- no, you have a vector of pointers which is not portable to the GPU. There are a plethora of AOS versus SOA questions on [SO] discussing this if you care to search for them

Comment: @talonmies Yes, that is correct. However, the idea is not to take this pointer vector to the GPU but to associate the elements of the data vector from the GPU to the correct element in the structure once the data has been transferred from device to host.

Comment: I understand your use case. But the point remains. Your "matrix" entries are separate allocations. They are not contiguous in memory. So there is no way that the GPU can copy to that discontinuous destination memory in a single transfer. There is no portability between host and device in that design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to directly bound the vector pointer of each to the testnode struct in order to "transfer" data without using any for loop ?

No, there is not.  When allocations are made using multiple calls to a host memory allocator such as `malloc` or `new` (thus creating multiple host pointers), you cannot transfer all of the referenced data to the device using a single `cudaMemcpyXXX` operation.  It will require one `cudaMemcpy` call per individually created host pointer.